# Leaking hose on new water softener. Using old hoses

Tags: hose, water-softener, leaking, seal

So we had to replace our water softener. After the installation we are getting some small leaking from the old hose. At first we thought it wasn't tightened all the way so we took them off and reattached. But still have some small leaking. I'm thinking the seal in the hose might be cracked/worn out.

Should I just buy new hoses and fittings?

I took at picture and circled where the water was leaking from. Any help would be appreciated.

Also should the plumber's tape be used?

[image]

Comment: Sometimes they'll drip for a few weeks, then stop up with mineral. Or just try new hoses now.

Comment: Or get new hide gaskets and try that. Or tighten down more and try that. Or...